# Is there a default binding to go into command-line mode and append a '!'?

Tags: command-line

Of course, I could make a mapping, but I was wondering if there's a default binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You can check yourself by going to [`:help index`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/index.txt.html#index) and searching for `!`.

You can add such a mapping with:

```
nnoremap <Leader>: :<Up>!
```